# Perform a client side form validation using the same logic of the server side validators

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, zend-framework

I need to create a JS module to perform a client side form validation with the following needs:

- Applying the same validation logic on both sides (server and client) without writing client-specific code (except for the module, of course)
- Error messages used by the JS module have to come from the server, so that I can have translated error message "for free"
- Developers should be able to reuse this feature with as less steps as possible.

The (server side) framework that I must use is Zend (vs 1.11.3).

My solution is the following one and I'd like to read your comments and feedback:

- I implemented a Zend Decorator that parses all zend form element validators and it adds to each form element a json containing all zend form validators information (messages templates, variables...).
- Then I implemented a JS Module (it wraps jQuery validation plugin) that parses that form element attribute and maps all server side validators into client side validators using settings (messages and variables) that are contained in the json.

At this point what I have is what I needed to have:
- There is the same logic on both sides
- I use the error messages that are provided by the server
- A developer can reuse it, adding a Zend Decorator to the form or to the form element and including the js module into the view.

It seems to be the right solution to my problem. Does it seem a good solution also for you?

Comment: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: I related this question to the exact same reference.

Comment: This is what I do, but its a custom implementation using CI, and custom form handling class.